# Debian virtualbox kernel install - Unknown symbol cpu_tlbstate

Tags: virtualbox, debian, kernel

I am currently attempting to install Oracle VirtualBox onto my Debian 9 machine. While the configuration attempts to build the kernel modules, I am thrown this message:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

As the configuration suggested, I ran dmesg and got this output:

```
[ 2477.381553] vboxdrv: disagrees about version of symbol cpu_tlbstate
[ 2477.381558] vboxdrv: Unknown symbol cpu_tlbstate (err -22)
```

I am fairly new to linux, and I have no idea how to fix this, with my knowledge A google search turned up nothing, and so I turned to this website. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**
It seems that the obvious solution (which skipped my mind completely) worked. I restarted my entire system, and now vitualbox seems to be working. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the obvious solution (which skipped my mind completely) worked. I restarted my entire system, and now vitualbox seems to be working. Sorry for the trouble!